# Columns are not displaying proper in MPDF table

Tags: html-table, mpdf

I'm using MPDF for printing reports.
I want to display table head only once and table body as per for loop.
When i'm printing result in table using echo then it will display proper but when i'm using MPDF then table is not in proper format.

Statement  echo $tr2.$data2; display proper structure

Statement $mpdf->WriteHTML($tr2.$data2); display collapse table

Below is my code :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totl_rows; $i++) {

        if($i == 0){
            $tr2 = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; " border="1" cellpadding="5"><tr>'
            . '<td style="width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Consolidation Month</td>'
            .'<td style="width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Transfer Entry No.</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Transfer Entry Dt.</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Amount</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Grant No.</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Fun Head No.</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Object Code</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Category Code</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">UTL Trans Type</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">UTL Dt.</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Utilised Amount</td></tr>';
        }
        else {
             $tr2= "<table  style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;' border='1'><tr></tr>";
        }
        $data2 = '<tr>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $consolidationmonth[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $tenumber[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $tedate1[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $amount[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $grantno[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $funcheadno[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $objectcode[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $categorycode[$i] .'</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $utl_trans_type[$i] . '</td>'
                  .'<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $utl_datee[$i] . '</td>'
                . '<td style=" width: 10%;">'. $utilised_amount[$i] . '</td></tr></table>';
        echo $tr2.$data2;
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($tr2.$data2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c'); 


$tr2 = '';
$data2 = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $totl_rows; $i++) {
    if($i == 0){

        // *** INICIALIZA TABLA Y ENCABEZADOS (TABLE/HEAD) ***

        $tr2 = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; " border="1" cellpadding="5"><tr>'
        . '<td style="width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Consolidation Month</td>'
        .'<td style="width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Transfer Entry No.</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Transfer Entry Dt.</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%; font-weight: bold;">Amount</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Grant No.</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Fun Head No.</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Object Code</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Category Code</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">UTL Trans Type</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">UTL Dt.</td>'
        . '<td style=" width: 10%;font-weight: bold;">Utilised Amount</td></tr>';
    }
    else {

        // *** ROWS ** FILAS ****

        $data2 .= '<tr>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $consolidationmonth[$i] . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $tenumber[$i] . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $tedate1[$i]  . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $amount[$i]   . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $grantno[$i]  . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $funcheadno[$i]    . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $objectcode[$i]    . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $categorycode[$i]  .'</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $utl_trans_type[$i] . '</td>'
              .'<td style=" width: 10%;">' . $utl_datee[$i]     . '</td>'
            . '<td style=" width: 10%;">'.   $utilised_amount[$i] . '</td></tr>';
    }   

}
// ** CIERRA TABLA ***
$data2 .= '</table>';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($tr2.$data2);
$mpdf->Output();
```